# Why can I match on the result of HashMap::get by both value and reference?

Tags: rust

Why does Rust allow both the match with `Some(v)` and `Some(&v)` in the following examples?

```rust
let mut dict1: HashMap<String, i32> = HashMap::new();
let word: String = String::new();

let get1 = dict1.get(word); 
match get1 {
    Some(v) => {
        value = *v;
        println!("Key returned is {}", value);
    }
    None => {}
}
```

```rust
let mut dict1: HashMap<String, i32> = HashMap::new();
let word: String = String::new();

let get1 = dict1.get(word);
match get1 {
    Some(&v) => {
        value = v;
        println!("Key returned is {}", value);
    }
    None => {}
}
```

Comment: Why would it not? Can you explain why this behavior creates a problem or raises a question?

Comment: Can you highlight the difference between your code blocks? It's not easy to spot.

Comment: If you match using `Some(v)`, the type of `v` will be `&i32`. If you match with `Some(&v)`, the type of `v` will be `i32`. The latter is allowed because `i32` is `Copy`, so you can extract `v` by value.

Comment: Similar behaviors are explained in here: [Destructuring Pointers](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/match/destructuring/destructure_pointers.html)

Answer (score 1):

```rust
match get1 {
    Some(v) => {
        value = *v;
        println!("Key returned is {}", value);
    }
    None => {}
}
```

In the first match, `Some(v)` matches with `get1` structure which is `Some(&i32)`. So, `v` type is `&i32`.

```rust
match get1 {
    Some(&v) => {
        value = *v;
        println!("Key returned is {}", value);
    }
    None => {}
}
```

In the second match, `Some(&v)` matches with `get1` structure which is `Some(&i32)`. in this case, `v` type is `i32`. In `Some(&v)` pattern, the `&v` is called a reference pattern [(see docs)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/patterns.html#struct-patterns)

As suggested by **Sven Marnach**, v type needs to be `Copy`, because the default binding mode in match arm follows move semantic.

The following snippet wont compile because `String` is not `Copy`.

```rust
let get_string = &String::from("meow");
let get1 = Some(meow);

match get1 {
    Some(&v) => {
        value = *v;
        println!("Key returned is {}", value);
    }
    None => {}
}
```

Just to be precise, it is the binding which requires `v` to be `Copy`, not the reference pattern.

You can see that the following code example use reference pattern on a non Copy type and compiles, because there is no binding.

```rust
fn main() {
    let meow = &String::from("meow");
    let my_ref = Some(meow);
    
    match my_ref {
        // just reference pattern here, no binding
        s @ Some(& _) => {println!("{:?}", s)}
        _ =>()
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This clarifies my query. Learning Rust is pretty exciting.

Comment: Cool if it helps. Welcome to the community.